# Nest js custom logger doubled console.logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, logging, nestjs

have a problem with implementing custom logger by extending default logger in NestJS. I followed documentation https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger#using-the-logger-for-application-logging.

```
import { Injectable, Logger, Scope } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.TRANSIENT })
export class LoggerService extends Logger {
  votes = 0;
  debug(message: string, trace?: string) {
    super.debug(message, trace);
  }

  error(message: string, trace?: string) {
    super.error(message, trace);
  }

  log(message: string, trace?: string) {
    this.votes = this.votes + 1;
    console.log(this.votes, 'log', message);
    super.log(message, trace);
  }

  verbose(message: string, trace?: string) {
    super.verbose(message, trace);
  }

  warn(message: string, trace?: string) {
    super.warn(message, trace);
  }
}
```

and in main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AllExceptionsFilter } from './shared/exception-filters/all-exception-filters';
import { LoggerService } from './shared/modules/logger/logger.service';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    logger: false,
  });
  app.useLogger(new LoggerService());

  app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter());

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

And in my controller

```
Controller('user')
export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService, private logger: LoggerService) {}

  @Get('/logger-example')
  getLoggerExample() {
    this.logger.log('it works ?');
    return 'loggerExample';
  }
```

And of course user module imports logger module.

I have two problems with that logger:

First one:

When i hit `user/logger-example`, i got two times log from Logger. It looks like that logger from `main.ts` exactly `app.useLogger(new LoggerService());` is executed along with injected instance, in future i want to put some async logger like pino or something and i'm afraid that log will be send two times. I assume something is wrong with my configuration, because it doesn't look like some common problem. What is more from default Logger i got properly one message.

The second one:

If i also inject that service to different module, for example payments. And made the same endpoint as for user, votes field on Logger class is always 0. Is it proper behaviour for transient scope of injection ? Because as i understood it should be injected per module. So in one module that counter shouldn't be reseted.

Is it properly configured ? Or it is normal behaviour ? I'm really afraid about two loggers executed in one `this.logger.log`.

Answer (score 1):

I found, that all elements passed into super.log are forced to be another log line. So duplicated logs are from two arguments at super.log. Please forward only message.

```
  log(message: string) {
    this.votes = this.votes + 1;
    console.log(this.votes, 'log', message);
    super.log(message);
  }
```